# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint, while 2 of 4 rows are different

Tags: python, django

I have a row in the DB that is:

```
order_id:    product_type_id:    is_child:    child_type_id:

  1                   2             True           3
```

I want to add a row with this code:

order = 1,

product.parent = 2

```
order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product_type=product.parent, 
                                                  child_type_id=None, is_child=False)
```

but it raises this error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "order_orderitem_order_id_product_type_id_ee5c1733_uniq"
>   DETAIL:  Key (order_id, product_type_id)=(1, 2) already exists.

while 2 of 4 rows are different, why I face this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your CONSTRAINTS, you have a constraint for order_id and product_type_id.
remove it and create a new one with all the features you wan together.
like: (order_item, product_type_id, child_product_type_id, is_child)

Comment: I had a standard M2M field and then I changed it to an M2M field with a through table and a `unique_together` constraint. It turns out that the old constraints were still stuck on the database table.

Answer (score 2):

Django has an issue with replication of data so i don't think you can have two objects with the same id unless it is a foreignkey or ManyToMany field.